# OpenCV FeatureDetector is not initialized

Tags: c++, opencv, feature-detection

I am trying to create a class where I shall find KeyPoints in an image. However, I get a ridiculous error I cannot figure out how to solve.

The problem is now that

```
this->detector
```

is zero, so it is for some reason not initialized properly. I have searched on google but I haven't found anything.

My headerfile looks as follows

```
    /*
 * FindKeyPoints.h
 *
 *  Created on: Jan 21, 2015
 *      Author: erikbylow
 */

#ifndef FINDKEYPOINTS_H_
#define FINDKEYPOINTS_H_

#include <vector>
#include <opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp>
#include <opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp>
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <opencv/highgui.h>
#include <opencv/cxcore.h>
using namespace std;

class FindKeyPoints {

private:
    // Create vector of KeyPoints to store the detected keypoint in
    vector<cv::KeyPoint> keyPointsOld;
    vector<cv::KeyPoint> keyPointsNew;
    // Threshold for similarity
    const int THRESHOLD = 10;

    // Instance(?) DescriptionExtractor and descriptor
    cv::Ptr<cv::DescriptorExtractor> descriptionExtractor;
    cv::Ptr<cv::FeatureDetector> detector;

public:
    FindKeyPoints(const string &METHOD);
    virtual ~FindKeyPoints();
    void detectKeypoints(cv::Mat& imgNew, cv::Mat& imgOld);
};

#endif /* FINDKEYPOINTS_H_ */
```

And constructor looks as

```
FindKeyPoints::FindKeyPoints(const string &METHOD) {
    cout<<METHOD<<endl;
    cv::initModule_features2d();
    this->detector = cv::FeatureDetector::create("SURF");
    //this->descriptionExtractor = cv::DescriptorExtractor::create(METHOD);
}
```

and a function I will use looks as:

```
// Input: The new image and the old image. Find Keypoints and extract the descriptors.
void FindKeyPoints::detectKeypoints(cv::Mat& imgNew,
        cv::Mat& imgOld) {
    if (this->detector == 0){
        cout<<"Hej"<<endl;
    }
//  this->detector->detect(imgNew, keyPointsNew);
//  this->detector->detect(imgOld, keyPointsOld);
}
```

I use cmake and (part of) my CMakeLists.txt looks like:

```
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${PROJECT_NAME} groundtruth ${OpenCV_LIBS} ${QT_LIBRARIES} 
${QGLViewer_LIBRARIES} ${OPENGL_gl_LIBRARY} GL
  glut)
```

Can it be that

```
${OpenCV_LIBS}
```

does not include libopencv_nonfree.so ?

Regards

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code. Did you include all the necessary .libs into your project ?

Comment: I put my CMakeLists.txt in the question

Comment: What is your "Ridiculous" error? Can you put it with full stack trace

Comment: #0  0x00007ffff792d02e in cv::FeatureDetector::detect(cv::Mat const&, std::vector<cv::KeyPoint, std::allocator<cv::KeyPoint> >&, cv::Mat const&) const ()
   from /usr/local/lib/libopencv_features2d.so.2.4
#1  0x000000000041be7b in FindKeyPoints::detectKeypoints(cv::Mat&, cv::Mat&) ()
#2  0x000000000041b79a in main ()

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the error is that I had only included

```
opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp
```

and not also

```
opencv2/nonfree/nonfree.hpp.
```